# Deployed SSIS packages fail to run

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS project built in Visual Studio 2022 and consists of several packages.  They all interrogate a source SQL server database and update a destination SQL server database (both 2016). These packages all run successfully from visual studio and do exactly what is required.  I have deployed them to the Catalogue and now tried running them but all seem to state failed in the SQL Server Package report with dozens of error messages - too many to list here.  The first error message though is always "The package cannot execute because it contains tasks that failed to load".

What is wrong here please? I have had a search for the first error message and other search inputs and some state it is a licensing issue but no other information.  The only thing of note I changed when deploying is in the properties of the "project" I enabled windows authentication and selected SQL server version as 2017 (there was no 2016)

Comment: "selected SQL server version as 2017 (there was no 2016)" - have you installed the latest VS SSIS extension? SQL 2016 should be available, which is needed to target SQL 2016.

Comment: have you got the latest updated to SQL Server Integration projects?  Version 1.2 allows you to target 2016.  2017 packages will not run on 2016.

Comment: Could be the .net version that is on the server vs what you have installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a limitation of earlier versions of the "SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022" for VS2022.

As many already pointed out, you need to install "SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022" v.1.2.

**Release Notes**

Version 1.2

- Release Date: Sep 12, 2023
- Build Version: 16.0.5314.0
- Tested against Visual Studio 2022 17.6
- What's new:

  **- SQL server 2016 is supported as target server version.**

Here is its download link:
[SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices)

NOTE from Question Poster - This worked but also had to ensure latest Visual C++ Redistributable was installed and link below for OLE DB 18.6.7 version because 19.3.1 did not work.  Also installed .NET Framework 4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#1867

Comment: Thanks - is this installed on development machine's visual studio and rebuild packages then redeploy?

Comment: Correct. It is for the VS2022 on the developer machine.

Comment: Thanks - this has improved and got some errors sorted but not all there is still several errors pointing to a connection issue and state "The requested OLE DB provider MSOLEDBSQL.1 is not registered".  The server ins windows server 2016.  Investigating this now

Comment: It seems that you need to downloads and install Microsoft OLEDB Driver **v.18.6.7**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#previous-releases

Comment: And stay away from the Microsoft OLEDB Driver v.19.* versions. They are for MS SQL Server 2022.